# XSLT Generic transform structural value type to single valued string

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I want to create an xslt transform which transforms a structural based attribute to a single valued string and preferably generic so no reference to named items from the input.

Example input:

```
<attr attr-name="items">
        <value type="structured">
          <component name="studentnummer">001001</component>
          <component name="achternaam">Bimans</component>
          <component name="voorletters">L./component>
          <component name="roepnaam">Leo</component>
          <component name="geboortedatum">09-08-1986</component>
          <component name="geslacht">V</component>
          <component name="mobiel_telefoonnummer">0612345678</component>
          <component name="voertaal_nl">Nederlands</component>
          <component name="voertaal_en">Dutch</component>
          <component name="extern_emailadres">L.Bimans@domain.nl</component>
        </value>
        <value type="structured">
          <component name="studentnummer">001002</component>
          <component name="achternaam">Boels</component>
          <component name="voorletters">F.</component>
          <component name="roepnaam">Felix</component>
          <component name="geboortedatum">04-02-1993</component>
          <component name="geslacht">M</component>
          <component name="voertaal_nl">Nederlands</component>
          <component name="voertaal_en">Dutch</component>
        </value>
</attr>
```

Should be translated to:

```
<attr attr-name="items">
    <value type="string">#studentnummer#001001#achternaam#Bimans#voorletters#L.#roepnaam#Leo#geboortedatum#09-08-1986#geslacht#V#mobiel_telefoonnummer#0612345678#voertaal_nl#Nederlands#voertaal_en#Dutch#extern_emailadres#L.Bimans@domain.nl></value>
    <value type="string">#studentnummer#001002#achternaam#Boels#voorletters#F.#roepnaam#Felix#geboortedatum#04-02-1993#geslacht#M#voertaal_nl#Nederlands#voertaal_en#Dutch</value>
<attr>
```

Another example:

```
<attr attr-name="links">
        <value type="structured">
          <component name="rel">self</component>
          <component name="href">http://192.83.206.98:9999/rds/basis/studenten/</component>
        </value>
        <value type="structured">
          <component name="rel">edit</component>
          <component name="href">http://192.83.206.98:9999/rds/basis/studenten/</component>
        </value>
        <value type="structured">
          <component name="rel">describedby</component>
          <component name="href">http://192.83.206.98:9999/rds/metadata-catalog/basis/studenten/</component>
        </value>
</attr>
```

Should be translated to:

```
<attr attr-name="links">
    <value type="string">#rel#self#href#http://192.83.206.98:9999/rds/basis/studenten/</value>
    <value type="string">#rel#edit#href#http://192.83.206.98:9999/rds/basis/studenten/</value>
    <value type="string">#rel#describedby#href#http://192.83.206.98:9999/rds/metadata-catalog/basis/studenten/</value>
</attr>
```

Transformation should be as generic as possible. In other words the same code could be used on both types of input data (if possible). So no references to attributes names, values or whatsoever.
Please note that the component name (from the structural) should be (preferably) included in the resulting string (as examples show) and after it the actual value should follow (all separated by a seperator character #).

Been trying to accomplish this but no luck up till now.

Also note i can only use xslt 1.0!

Thanks!

Comment: It's always useful to show your best attempt. Then we can see how much you already know and where the sticking point is.

Answer (score 0):

To do this generically, I'd first start with the identity to copy existing XML:

```xml
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then have a template that matches any elements that have the `type="structured"` attribute (i.e. all your value elements). For those that are matched, we'll copy the element and add a `type="string"` attribute. And we'll set the text of that element to be made up of ##'s plus the value of the name atttribute and the text of every child element. Like this:

```xml
<xsl:template match="*[@type = 'structured']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="type">string</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">##<xsl:value-of select="@name" />##<xsl:value-of select="text()" /></xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is generic enough that all you realy need is a node with `type="structure"` and children with a name attribute.

Comment: Thanks! This was just the code where i was looking for. Tested it; it works!

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to have any element and attribute names the question arises: "How do we want to identify the nodes (both element and attribute), that contain our values?"

The only other way, I know of, would be to assume fixed node positions within the source trees.

The following XSLT does it, as long as the structure keeps staying:

```
attr
  value
    component
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output 
        method="xml"
        indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- node()[self::*] tests for an element node-type, 
         thus we only process element nodes, this way -->
    <xsl:template match="/node()[self::*]">
        <!-- we create a new element, that has its name set 
             to the name of the current node, indicated by '.' -->
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
            <!-- We now create an attribute for the element we are creating.
                 Handling the attribute like this is only going 
                 to work out the way we want it, if the attribute,
                 whose  name we want to replicate is the first attribute 
                 of the element. -->
            <xsl:attribute name="{name(attribute::node())}">
                <xsl:value-of select="attribute::node()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!-- within our current node (which is 'attr') we iterate 
                 through each contained node and create an output element, which will
                 be the 'value' element. -->
            <xsl:for-each select="node()[self::*]">
                <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">string</xsl:attribute>
                    <!-- within each 'value' element, we iterate through all 'component'
                         elements, constructing out text node dynamically. -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()[self::*]">
                        <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="attribute::node()"/>
                        <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- we suppress any built-in templates for text-node processing, otherwise we
         would get them in the output, too. -->
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

P.S. I don't know why you are constrained to using XSLT-1.0 but you could also get the Saxon program from http://saxonica.com. The *SaxonHE* (see downloads) edition is open source and free to use.